# Indexing numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to perform pairs bootstrap and I have some problems when indexing the bootstrap samples. I will show a brief piece of code that matches the problem I am facing. How should I index the sample to get the bootstrap sample?

This is the data:

```
Y = [1,4,2,5,3,2,4,6]
X = [1,2,3,4,3,1,5,2]
```

First of all I create the index:

```
ind = np.arange(len(X))
```

Secondly I perform bootstrap on the index:

```
ind_b = np.random.choice(ind, len(ind))
```

And finally I try to filter both variables with the bootstrap index:

```
Y_b = Y[ind_b] 
X_b = X[ind_b]
```

Doing this I get an error message:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Could someone explain how I can do it correctly?

Comment: `Y` and `X` are only a Python `list`, they do not know how to index based off `np.array`. You can instead change `Y = np.array(Y)` and then you can index like that

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `X` and `Y` are only Python `list`'s in this case. If you were to do `type(Y)` you would get `list`. Since you are indexing into a list with `np.array`, Python has no idea what that is and throws the error because you are doing invalid operations on a `list`. Instead, you need `X` and `Y` to be type `np.array` as well

```
>>> ind_b
array([6, 2, 7, 4, 0, 5, 7, 0])
>>> np.array(Y)[ind_b]
array([4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1])
>>> Y = np.array(Y)
>>> X = np.array(X)
>>> Y_b = Y[ind_b]
>>> Y_b
array([4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1])
>>> X_b = X[ind_b]
>>> X_b
array([5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1])
```

A quick fix is to change it so the assignments are:

```
Y = np.array([1,4,2,5,3,2,4,6])
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,3,1,5,2])
```

Comment: Great oberservation.  +1

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. It works perfectly.